# Use vimdiff in place of diff to compare configs during package updates

Tags: apt, package-management, diff

Sometimes when you perform packages updates, you'll be prompted with action to take when apt tries to update packages which contain updated configs.

I'd like to know if there's a way to invoke vimdiff in place of diff when pressing D in this question.

```
Configuration file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** defaults.list (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? D
```

Comment: There is an open feature request: [bug #473996](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=473996)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish there was (I should do something about that, I suppose). But no.

However, you can do:

- Press `Z`.
- `vimdiff /etc/gnome/defaults.list{,.dpkg-new}`